# added a temporary env variable in react app, how to remove it?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, dotenv

added temporary env variable using the command `($env:REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE = "abcdef") -and (npm start)` based on https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/ doc. According to doc, it is supposed to live only for that shell session. But when I restart the app again with just `npm start` - the variable still exists. How to remove this?

Comment: Did you restart the shell?

Comment: You mentioned restarting the app - but I assume that's in the same shell session. Have you tried a new shell session? It *should* be local to that shell.

Comment: It worked after restarting the shell, thanks Sami and slothluvchunk

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer to this in case other folks wind up here and don't see the comments.

The issue here is that restarting the application and restarting the shell are two different things.

To clear out these custom environmental variables, close and restart the shell session, not just the node app.